# textbox leave event is set,when textbox consist alphabet ,the other clear button cant delete it

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox leave Event to prevent user key in alphabet. It works anywhere but also I have one clear button to clear the textbox, it can clear it but when the textbox has alphabet it will not work to clear it, how can I lost focus when clicking the clear button and i click the button it will show the error message that I set when textbox consist alphabet

```
 Private Sub InputNumberTextBox_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InputNumberTextBox.Leave
    Dim Regex As String = "[a-zA-Z ]"
    Dim Number As New Regex(Regex)
    If Number.IsMatch(InputNumberTextBox.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Cause - Please Enter Number Only" & vbCrLf & "Focus - Can't enter space" & vbCrLf &
               "Clear - Do Not have space space when delete", vbExclamation, "Error For Alphabet and Space Bar")
        InputNumberTextBox.Focus()
        Name = False
    Else

        Name = True
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub ClearNumberButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearNumberButton.Click
    Dim clear As MsgBoxResult
    If Not InputNumberTextBox.Lines.Count = 0 Then
        clear = MsgBox("Sure Want To delete All?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Delete Message")
        If clear = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            InputNumberTextBox.Text = ""
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("No Number To Clear", vbExclamation)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. If you want to validate a control when the user tries to navigate away, handle the `Validating` evnt.

Comment: so my clear button code put in to validating event?

Comment: No, I am fairly certain jmcilhinney meant you should use the `_Validating` event instead of the `_Leave` event to achieve your goal

Comment: i ady move the code to validating event but also same

Comment: Use the Validating event instead, set e.Cancel = True when you're not happy.  The ClearNumberButton control should have its CausesValidation property set to False so it can always be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

instead of
   `InputNumberTextBox.Text = ""`
write 
    `InputNumberTextBox.Text = "0"`

or you change your
    `If Number.IsMatch(InputNumberTextBox.Text) Then`
 to
    `If Number.IsMatch(InputNumberTextBox.Text) And (InputNumberTextBox.Text <> String.Empty) Then`

So in the first case there is a neutral number and the validating event don't find a missmatch.
in the second case you only give a messagebox when there is actually a text in the textbox

Comment: I haven't reviewed if your code fixes the OP's issue, but regarding your second approach (the changed if-block), I would use `If (InputNumberTextBox.Text <> String.Empty) AndAlso (Number.IsMatch(InputNumberTextBox.Text) Then`. A regex-check can be relatively performance intensive and should not be performed when not necessary. For this same reason, this approach would also have my personal preference over your first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I entered "74?" It would pass your regex test but it would not be a valid number. There is a place for Regex but when you are checking for a number use the appropriate `.TryParse` Each numeric type has this method. I arbitrarily chose the Integer datatype.

There is no need for a clear button because the text will be selected. Anyone remotely familiar with Windows will know the delete key or any key will remove existing text. Be sure there is an exit button with `.CausesValidation` set to false or your user will never be able to escape.

```
Private Sub InputNumberTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles InputNumberTextBox.Validating
    Dim myInteger As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(InputNumberTextBox.Text, myInteger) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
        e.Cancel = True
        InputNumberTextBox.SelectAll()
        Return
    End If
    'Continue processing the input
    MessageBox.Show(myInteger.ToString)
End Sub
```